# not displaying page because of for/foreach loops

Tags: php, for-loop

I know there's something wrong with my code because the page never loads so there's somethign wrong with either the for loop or foreach loop. The topRankings variable is set correct and giving the right value.

```
<?php 
        for ($i = 0; $i >= count($topRankings); $i++){
            foreach($topRankings[$i] as $k=>$v)
            {
                $seperator = ($elements == $count) ? '' : '<hr />'; 
                $name = (!isset($row['character_name'])) ? 'TBD' : $row['character_name'];
                $count++;
            ?>
                <li><span class="red"><?php echo $name; ?></span></li>
            <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Print_r of $topRankings

```
 Array ( [0] =&gt; Array ( [character_name] =&gt; Kid Wonder ) [1] =&gt; Array ( [character_name] =&gt; Ryu Satoshi ) [2] =&gt; Array ( [character_name] =&gt; Oriel ) [3] =&gt; Array ( [character_name] =&gt; \"The Ladies Man\" Luscious Landon ) [4] =&gt; Array ( [character_name] =&gt; \"The Outlaw\" Mike Mayhem ) )
```

**EDIT:** 
I'm getting an undefined count variable and undefined variable elements and undefined offset: 5.

```
<?php 
        $count = count($topRankings);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
            foreach($topRankings[$i] as $k=>$v)
            {
                $seperator = ($elements == $count) ? '' : '<hr />'; 
                $name = (!isset($row['character_name'])) ? 'TBD' : $row['character_name'];
                $count++;
            ?>
                <li><span class="red"><?php echo $name; ?></span></li>
            <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: How many times is it looping? Like, whats the value of `$topRankings` and how many rows are in `$topRankings[x]`?

Comment: If I do a print_r of topRankings it looks like this: Array ( [0] =&gt; Array ( [character_name] =&gt; Kid Wonder ) [1] =&gt; Array ( [character_name] =&gt; Ryu Satoshi ) [2] =&gt; Array ( [character_name] =&gt; Oriel ) [3] =&gt; Array ( [character_name] =&gt; \"The Ladies Man\" Luscious Landon ) [4] =&gt; Array ( [character_name] =&gt; \"The Outlaw\" Mike Mayhem ) )

Comment: @Mr.Magoo Can you post the output of print_r in a code block at the bottom of your post? It'll be easier to read that way.

Comment: Those darn foreach loops causing trouble again?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
for ($i = 0; $i >= count($topRankings); $i++) {
```

Should be:

```
$count = count($topRankings);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) {
```

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
for ($i = 0; $i >= count($topRankings); $i++){
```

Should be:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($topRankings); $i++){
```

Comment: But then I get an undefined count variable.

Comment: @Mr.Magoo, sorry, it should be `for ($i = 0; $i < count($topRankings); $i++){` as `count($topRankings)` is 1 greater than the max index. But why are you not just using a foreach instead of the for?

Answer (score 1):

The *undefined count* happens because $count is 5, and since you use <= you iterate from 0 to 5, which is 6 items... the last time 'round throws the error.

In other words

```
$count = 5
$count != count(range(0,5));
$count == count(range(0,4));
```

Incidentally I also wonder why you need the foreach at all right now...

```
<?php 
$topRankings =  array(
    0 => array('character_name' => 'Kid Wonder'),
    1 => array('character_name' => 'Ryu Satoshi' ),
    2 => array('character_name' => 'Oriel' ),
    3 => array('character_name' => '"The Ladies Man" Luscious Landon' ),
    4 => array('character_name' => '"The Outlaw" Mike Mayhem')
);

$count = count($topRankings);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $name = (!isset($topRankings[$i]['character_name'])) ? 'TBD' : $topRankings[$i]['character_name'];
    echo '<li><span class="red">' . $name . '</span></li>';
    if ($i < $count-1) echo '<hr>';
}
```